# How to retrieve parse additional column data

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I tried to get data from parse's "additional" column but it doesn't seem to work normally. When I write `PFUser.currentuser.username`, it gives me the username of the current user, but it doesn't work with the additional field.

Answer (score 0):

let userQuery = PFUser.query();

userQuery?.includeKey("additional");

...
let addtitionalDesc = userQuery["addtitional"] as String

Comment: it says : "cannot subscript a value of type  PFQuery? with an index of type String"